# Travis-ci console asks for answers

Tags: grails, travis-ci

How can i answer a question made by the console in travis-ci? I made a script that is downloading gvm but right after it completes i receive something like this:

"Do you want grails 2.1.5 to be set as default? (Y/n):"

Right after this question the build can't go foward, i tried to use expects but i was not very successful, my travis.yml is this:

language: groovy

jdk:
- oraclejdk7

before_install:

- rm -rf ~/.gvm
- curl -s get.gvmtool.net > ~/install_gvm.sh
- chmod 775 ~/install_gvm.sh
- ~/install_gvm.sh
- source "/home/travis/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
- sdk install grails 2.1.5
- echo "gvm_auto_answer=Y" > ~/.sdkman/bin/config

branches:
  only:
    - master

script: grails test-app --non-interactive

**EDIT** Grails wrapper is not working as you can see here

https://travis-ci.org/jpms2/ResS/builds/81761164

I seemed to find a problem like mine that happened with gvm instalation, the solution to this problem was a command like this:

- echo "gvm_auto_answer=true" >> ~/.gvm/etc/config

So i tried to use this command and had no success:

- echo "gvm_auto_answer=Y" >> ~/.sdkman/etc/config

Comment: Use the grails wrapper? http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.1.5/guide/single.html#wrapper

Comment: @tim_yates This is an interactive message from gvm (sdkman). Grails wrapper won't help I suppose. I do not see any non-interactive or silent install in sdkman. Is there any?

Comment: But why use sdkman to install grails on a Travis box?

Comment: I thought that's why grails wrapper was created?

Comment: http://blog.freeside.co/2013/02/26/grails-builds-on-travis-ci/

Comment: Agree using wrapper **instead of gvm**.

Comment: Well this also made me think whether having a silent option in sdkman can be a good feature? @tim_yates

Comment: Yeah, options for `--default` and `--silent` sound like a good idea :-)

Comment: Tried to use grails wrapper but i'm getting another error, says this: "chmod: cannot access `grailsw': No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

I did find a way to pass the log message, using

- echo sdkman_auto_answer=true > ~/.sdkman/etc/config

my travis.yml file is like this now:

language: groovy

jdk:
- oraclejdk7

before_install:

- rm -rf ~/.gvm
- curl -s get.gvmtool.net > ~/install_gvm.sh
- chmod 775 ~/install_gvm.sh
- ~/install_gvm.sh
- echo sdkman_auto_answer=true > ~/.sdkman/etc/config
- source "/home/travis/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
- sdk install grails 2.1.5

branches:
  only:
    - master

script: grails test-app --non-interactive